# Getting JSON info to Material-UI dialoge

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, material-ui

I'm working with JSON file with information. I'm ising also React with Material-UI to style and render them. I have some a JSON file which looks like this:

```
[{"item":123456",
  "description":"Jacket",
  "colors":[{
     "code":"blue",
     "sizes":[{
        "code":"L",
```

And so on. One item can have more then one sizes with diffrent size-codes. I'm using dialog from Material-UI with React. I want to generete a simple dropdown meny with all code sizes in dialog for clicked item. Here I show you how I get information about item to dialog:

```
export default class SelectFieldExampleCustomLabel extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: 1};
}

handleChange(event, index, value) {
    this.setState({value});
}

render() {
    return (
        <SelectField value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
            {dataSet.map(tile => (
            <MenuItem value={tile.item} label={tile.item} primaryText={tile.item}></MenuItem>
            ))}
        </SelectField>
    );
}
```

That works but it gets my all item I got in my JSON file. It is just a test, but I want that this one will generete sizes for clicked item.

I got also another way to get data from JSON to the dialog:

```
    handleOpen(tile){
    this.setState({
        open: true,
        tileTitle: tile.description,
        tileImg: "img/" + tile.item + ".png",
        tileCategory: tile.category,
        tileGender: tile.gender,
        tileSizes: tile.item
    });
};

<Dialog
                    title={this.state.tileTitle}
                    actions={actions}
                    modal={false}
                    open={this.state.open}
                    contentStyle={styles.dialog}
                    onRequestClose={this.handleClose.bind(this)}
                >

                    <img src={this.state.tileImg} style={styles.dialogImg} />
                    <div style={styles.textBox}>
                        <h4>{this.state.tileCategory}</h4>
                        <p><b>Gender:</b> {this.state.tileGender}</p>
                        <SelectFieldExampleCustomLabel></SelectFieldExampleCustomLabel>
                    </div>

                </Dialog>
```

Any tips how can I fix what I'm asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track with using state. You wrote, "I want that this one will generete sizes for clicked item" but it's unclear if the code you've shown does that initial click. Assuming it does though, you could alter your handler as follows:

```
handleChange(event, index, value) {
  sizes = []
  for (colors of dataSet[<index of selected value>].colors {
    for (size of colors.sizes) {
      if (! sizes.includes(size) {
        // Or you could use Set type for sizes and use sizes.add(size) w/o if
        sizes.push(size)  
      }
    }
  }
  this.setState({
    value: value,
    sizes: sizes,
  })
}
```

Then in your render method for the size drop down, you would do sizes.map(...) or if you use Set type for sizes, Sizes.forEach(...).